# Is it okay to use AUTO_INCREMENT=1 before each post to database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, auto-increment

I am using wordpress, and I made a page to upload information to a database. Are there any potential problems with adding `$wpdb->query('ALTER TABLE sermons AUTO_INCREMENT=1');` before inserting in information to the table? I want to make sure, in case something is deleted, that the ID's begin at the next number.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be necessary if you setup the table correctly. Your table should use $wpdb->prefix by the way. Did you set this up manually or use WordPress (dbDelta)?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: OK just go into the DB and set the auto increment. $wpdb->prefix adds the table prefix. The default is wp_ Your table should be called {prefix}tablename

Answer (score -1):

I just copy this from mysql page\

> To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

Comment: I don't want a specific number, just the next number. I have this run every time information is posted.